# Use railsadmin as root app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin as main app and i would like to have it accessible via `/` and not `/admin` path.

My current routes files looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
  root 'dashboard#index'
end
```

dashboard is just a simple page with a link to `/admin` that i want to get rid off.

A simple `mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/', as: 'rails_admin'` does not work out as there is a redirect loop (from devise i guess).

Logs are

```
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 10.0.16.183:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/" for 10.0.16.244 at 2016-01-15 14:19:55 +0100
Cannot render console from 10.0.16.244! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.16.244 at 2016-01-15 14:19:55 +0100
Cannot render console from 10.0.16.244! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"model_name"=>"users", "id"=>"sign_in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.16.244 at 2016-01-15 14:19:55 +0100
Cannot render console from 10.0.16.244! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"model_name"=>"users", "id"=>"sign_in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


...
continues a couple of time after timeout
```

Tried several things but nothing worked out.

Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was a devise issue and i found a solution in https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Troubleshoot 
Had to switch devise infront of engine mounting.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/', as: 'rails_admin'
  root 'dashboard#index'
end
```

Comment: Is it safe to remove `root 'dashboard#index'` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying the root address?

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/', as: 'rails_admin'
```

Comment: Yes, it does not work out as devise is giving a redirect loop. Extended my questions with relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

For me following worked to redirect user with admin role directly to the rails_admin dashboard page.

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  authenticated :user, ->(u) { u.has_role?(:admin) } do
    root to: "rails_admin/main#dashboard", as: :admin_root
  end
```